# How to make this skybox rotate (Unity)?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, animation, shader

Ok, I need to use this skybox shader because it allows for a blending I need, issue is I also need it to rotate (animated rotate), as described here: https://answers.unity.com/questions/651780/rotate-skybox-constantly.html

Shader:

```
Shader "RenderFX/Skybox Blended" {

 Properties {
     _Tint ("Tint Color", Color) = (.5, .5, .5, .5)
     _Tint1 ("Tint Color one", Color) = (.5, .5, .5, .5)
     _Tint2 ("Tint Color two", Color) = (.5, .5, .5, .5)
     _Blend ("Blend", Range(0.0,1.0)) = 0.5
     _Skybox1 ("Skybox one", Cube) = ""
     _Skybox2 ("Skybox two", Cube) = ""
 }

 SubShader {
     Tags { "Queue" = "Background" }
     Cull Off
     Fog { Mode Off }
     Lighting Off        
     Color [_Tint]
     Pass {
         SetTexture [_Skybox1] { combine texture }
         SetTexture [_Skybox2] { constantColor (0,0,0,[_Blend]) combine texture lerp(constant) previous }
         SetTexture [_Skybox2] { combine previous +- primary, previous * primary }
     }

 }

 Fallback "RenderFX/Skybox", 1
 }
```

I am very new to skybox shaders and tried integrating their code, but it just drew errors. How can I animate rotation on this skybox?

```
RenderSettings.skybox.SetFloat("_Rotation", Time.time*0.4f);
```

did not work either.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem with my skybox by using the line of code you wrote at the end but made a change to the skybox first. Select your skybox material then in the inspector panel go to Shader>Skybox and select "Skybox/6 Sided". If you have a cubemap material for your skybox you can also use the "Cubemap" option.

[image: Skybox Inspector]

The code would be:

```
void Update () {
    RenderSettings.skybox.SetFloat("_Rotation", Time.time * 0.4f);
}
```