# Is it possible to rotate the skybox on the z or x axis?

Tags: unity-game-engine

im currently working on a Unity project and im trying to make the skybox rotate vertically but so far i've only been able to make it rotate horizontally. Is it possible to make it rotate the way I want or am I just wasting my time?

Comment: I don't know if it fully satisfies your request, but I suggest you take a look, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51387887/how-to-make-this-skybox-rotate-unity

Comment: Thanks but that's what i managed to achieve so far, thing is, it rotates on the horizontal axis, making it look like you are spinning on your feet. But what im trying to do is to make it rotate on the vertical axis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#1 You should show what you already tried in your question. Explain exactly what you are doing and include any code.

#2 I dunno what you already tried so I cant help you there, but if you cant get it to work here is a workaround...
Make a skybox camera, then you can rotate that camera any way you want.

- make a new camera
- give it a smaller depth value than your other cameras so it renders 1st
- Set its culling mask to nothing and clear flags to skybox so its only rendering skybox
- Set clear flags of your other cameras to depth only so they render whatever meshes they see on top of your skybox cameras image.